# How to successfully logout using a Rails 6 API with devise and JWT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, devise, jwt

I've been stuck for days and searching but I cannot find a correct solution to logout from a devise session using JWT. I had a front made with react and everything works fine on login and searching, but when I logout the page if I don't make a refresh I can't login. I leave the code from devise session controller along side the application controller, route and my middeware build to use redux with my front (I'm working with React to). Thanks in advance and I you need something else, let me know.

**Devise::SessionsController**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Api::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json, :html
  
  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  private
    def revoke_token(token)
      # Decode JWT to get jti and exp values.
      begin
        secret = Rails.application.credentials.jwt_secret
        jti = JWT.decode(token, secret, true, algorithm: 'HS256', verify_jti: true)[0]['jti']
        exp = JWT.decode(token, secret, true, algorithm: 'HS256')[0]['exp']
        user = User.find(JWT.decode(token, secret, true, algorithm: 'HS256')[0]['sub'])
        sign_out user
        # Add record to blacklist.
        time_now = Time.zone.now.to_s.split(" UTC")[0]
        sql_blacklist_jwt = "INSERT INTO jwt_blacklist (jti, exp, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('#{ jti }', '#{ Time.at(exp) }', '#{time_now}', '#{time_now}');"
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_blacklist_jwt)
      rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature, JWT::VerificationError, JWT::DecodeError
        head :unauthorized
      end
    end

    def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
      render json: resource
    end

    def respond_to_on_destroy
      token = request.headers['Authorization'].split("Bearer ")[1]
      revoke_token(token)
      request.delete_header('Authorization')
      render json: :ok
    end
end
```

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_action :authenticate_user

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = %i[username email password password_confirmation remember_me]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: added_attrs)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: added_attrs)
  end

  private

  def authenticate_user
    if request.headers['Authorization'].present?
      token = request.headers['Authorization'].split("Bearer ")[1]
      begin
        jwt_payload = JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.credentials.jwt_secret).first
        @current_user_id = jwt_payload['sub']
      rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature, JWT::VerificationError, JWT::DecodeError
        head :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end

  def authenticate_user!(options = {})
    head :unauthorized unless signed_in?
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= super || User.find(@current_user_id)
  end

  def signed_in?
    @current_user_id.present?
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, skip: %i[registrations sessions passwords]

  namespace :api do
    devise_scope :user do
      post 'signup', to: 'registrations#create'
      post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
      delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
      get 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
    end

    resources :notes
    resources :searches
    
    get 'get_places', to: 'searches#get_places'
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**middleware.js**

```
import * as constants from './constants';

import axios from 'axios';
import { logoutUser } from './actions/authActionCreators'

export const apiMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
    if (action.type !== constants.API) return next(action);

    dispatch({ type: constants.TOGGLE_LOADER });
    const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:3001';
    const AUTH_TOKEN = getState().user.token;
    if (AUTH_TOKEN)
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}`;

    const { url, method, success, data, postProcessSuccess, postProcessError } = action.payload;

    console.log('AUTH_TOKEN '+AUTH_TOKEN);
    console.log('url '+url);

    axios({
        method,
        url: BASE_URL + url,
        data: data ? data : null,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': '*/*'
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: constants.TOGGLE_LOADER });
        if (success) dispatch(success(response));
        if (postProcessSuccess) postProcessSuccess(response);
    }).catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: constants.TOGGLE_LOADER });
        if (typeof(error.response) === "undefined") {
            console.warn(error);
            postProcessError('An error has ocurred');
        } else {
            if (error.response && error.response.status === 403)
                dispatch(logoutUser());
            if (error.response.data.message) {
                if (postProcessError) postProcessError(error.reponse.data.message);
            }
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?